# Finding occurence of one word in the second using string methods

Tags: python

So I have a function that takes in two words with only letters and returns True iff the second word occurs within the first word in the exact same order as it is in the word.

For example, if I had:

`>>> within('builder','bild')` it would return True as bild, occurs in the first word, in the same order as it is in the second word.

An example of a false statement would be:

`>>> within('builder', 'bidl')` as even though the letters in word2 are in word1, they are in a different order.

What I tried to do is use a for loop and range to get the index of when the first occurence of each letter in word 2 happens in word 1, but it doesn't work in this case:

`>>> within('aaaacadgt', 'cat')` because the index of a would give me the first index and result in the return value to be False, even though it's True.

Just a note that I can't use any methods aside from strings.

So no Lists, Dictionaries, Tuples, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There's a fun way to handle this by using regex:

```
import re

def within(big, small):
    # we will do this with a regular expression, checking for each character in order,
    #   with any number of any kind of character in between them, and before/after
    #   '.*' will get this.
    rexp = '.*' + '.*'.join(re.escape(small)) + '.*'
    # then, we just see if the regex matches
    return (re.match(rexp, big) is not None)
```

---

That said, it's also possible to do without regular expressions. Consider a recursive approach:

```
def within(big, small):
    # base case: return True on an empty string
    if small == '':
        return True
    # Find the first occurrence in `big` of the first character
    try:
        idx = big.index(small[0])
        # If it's there, then search for the next character, after that point
        #   by using string slicing
        return within(big[(idx + 1):], small[1:])
    except Indexerror:
        # If the first character of small is not in big, then small can't occur in big.
        return False
```

This could be generalized into a non-recursive approach by keeping track of the indices somehow. It's similar to what you were doing - but it *cuts off the front of the string* to avoid the error you're getting.